# Pdf report showing no output in oracle apps although showing output in oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, oracle-apps, oracleapplications, oracle-ebs

"Report showing no output in oracle apps although showing output in oracle reports ?"
I need to get output in oracle apps ?

I have two date parameters in the report **`p_from_date and p_to_date`** ? If i give values to parameters then it do not show output and also if i do not give values to parameters then it also do not show output. although the report showing output in oracle reports absolutely fine. Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you run that Apps report in core Reports (outside of Apps) ? Could there be some date format differences ?

Comment: Please be more specific and try to do some research of your own. Not only to search for shortest answer. Do you mean Oracle Reports Builder?

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with the RTF you are using.
Make sure it is good.

for testing use a simple Rtf with only one column and check.

Also please view XMl for this report and check for error or if the xml is properly closed or not.

Most of the time the issue will be with above two cases only